# Why is this loop repeating each string multiple times?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, boolean

I'm in an intro to python class and am having some trouble understanding the boolean loop situation I've gotten myself into.  I've tried searching for a similar situation but so far I haven't found any answers which are close to what I'm doing (or at least that I could see the similarity :/) so I'm asking for help. The zybook is inputting 4 strings of names and my last loop is looping each one multiple times (over 5000 apparently).  I don't know how to make it only do each string once...I keep trying different fixes but so far I just break other parts of the code which are functioning.  I'd appreciate any insight into how I can fix this problem.  Thanks so much!  Here is the code:

```
user_bool = "true"
user_input = input("Enter input string:\n")

while user_bool != "false":
    if "," not in user_input:
        print ("Error: No comma in string.\n")
        user_input = input("Enter input string:\n")
        user_bool = "true"

    else:
        user_bool = "false"
        continue    

s_bool = "true"

while s_bool != "false":  
    if ',' in user_input:
        s_input = user_input.split(",")
        print ("First word:",s_input[0].strip())
        print ("Second word:",s_input[1].strip())
        print ("\n")
        s_bool = "true"
    else: 
        s_bool = "false"
        break
```

It's not giving me an error message other than I have an open loop so it's repeating over 5000 times.

Comment: Is there a reason for using strings with the contents `"true"` and `"false"` instead of the boolean values `True` and `False` built into the language?

Comment: Hmm well I was getting errors and found an example of a similar problem which had true and false written that way.  When I changed my code (in other ways) I just changed that too and things started working so I thought I'd been doing it wrong.  I'll change it and see if that makes any difference.   Thanks!

Comment: @ggorlen the input() function would return a string though.

Comment: @gilch I don't see why that matters. No boolean comparisons are being done against the input string.

Comment: In the current version of the code, that is true, but I'd assume an earlier iteration did that. I'm not saying it should be done that way now, just that that is probably why Amorky used a string in the first place.

Comment: Regardless, the endless loop is clear. The first loop forces the user to input a string with a comma. Once the `user_input` string has a comma in it, the second loop will never terminate.

Comment: I did try to modify that a few times.  I added an if statement about a comma being 'not in' the user_input variable.  I also tried an 'elif' statement regarding 'q' as an input because zybook does input one to end the sequence.  However none of that stopped the endless loop.  I'm just not thinking of this properly.  Loops are always where I have issues :/

Comment: Thanks for all your helpful comments!  i figured out how to make this work!